# Query multiple ranges of price based on checkboxes

Tags: sql, angular, checkbox, between

I'm trying to write a SQL query for multiple price range based on the number of checkboxes I have.

I creating the checkbox based on price range that coming from the server (for example: 100-200,200-400,400-600). The user can choose 1 option, 2 option or all 3. But when the user check 100-200 and 400-600 I can't return to him 350.

I'm new to SQL and I can't find out how I can make x ranges based on checkbox I have.

I don't know how to start writing this lines of codes.

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from Test 
where (price >= 100 and price <= 200) 
   or (price >= 300 and price <= 400)
```

Comment: this is hardcoded, I have multi checkbox that will change all times. I need to take the ranges from the checkboxes (this is not my problem) and.send it to sql. I need to asume that I don't know how much ranges I have.